# Reading Raw Data in SAS using pointer control

Tags: sas, raw-data

I understand how to use pointer control to search for a phrase in the raw data and then read the value into a SAS variable.  I need to know how to tell SAS to stop reading the raw data when it encounters a particular phrase.
For example in the below code I want to read the data only between phrases **Start** and **Stop**.  So the Jelly should not be part of the output

```
data work.two;
input @"1" Name :$32.;
datalines;
Start 1 Frank 6 
1 Joan 2
3 Sui Stop
1 Jelly 4
5 Jose 3
;
run;
```

[image: Current Output]

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really combine those into a single pass through the file.  The problem is that the `@'1'` will skip past the line with `STOP` in it so there is no way your data step will see it.

Pre-process the file.

```
filename copy temp;
data _null_;
  file copy ;
  retain start 0 ;
  input ;
  if index(_infile_,'Start') then start=1;
  if start then put _infile_;
  if index(_infile_,'Stop') then stop;
datalines;
Start 1 Frank 6
1 Joan 2
3 Sui Stop
1 Jelly 4
5 Jose 3
;

data work.two;
  infile copy ;
  input @"1" Name :$32. @@;
run;
```

You can make the logic to detect what parts of the source file to include as complex as you need.

Answer (score 0):

All names are the second position from the left of each row, so name could be got by scan function, if there is 'Stop' in the row then stop loop.

```
data work.two;
input @@;
Name=scan(_infile_,-2);
if indexw(_infile_,'Stop')>0 then stop;
input;
datalines;
Start 1 Frank 6 
1 Joan 2
3 Sui Stop
1 Jelly 4
5 Jose 3
;
run;
```